# Sudden Visual Studio 2017 SmartDeviceException DEP6200 error

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-mobile, smart-device

Yesterday I was able to Code with VS2017 on my Win 7 (upgrade to 10)/Lumia 950XL.
I am writing on an UWP-App which targets Mobile-Devices and PC.

I was happily writing on my app and debugging it on my phone, everything worked great. The suddenly I had to leave and I ran the app a last time on my phone, to see if my changes worked -> worked. So I sent my Laptop on Standby and after returning I wanted to run it again -> This Error appeared:

[image]

Common Answer:

- I tried to turn of "Developer Mode" - run and expected the error.
- Then turn "Developer Mode" on - run and expected it to work - it didn't.

I also tried to connect my Phone without connection to W-Lan.
I also tried to repair VS2015 (I am not able to repair VS2017 - somehow).

I did not try to uninstall and install because that would take a full day away and I need the time to Code.

Open for help.

Edit:

I have this Phone and this Laptop, no other Windows Devices to debug. (and not enough RAM to run an emulator that would help).

EDIT2: [image]

Comment: you image is not displaying

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your issue. I deployed the project when the phone was not connected to the computer and it will throw `DEP6200` error. Please check if your phone  properly connected to your computer. If your device  connected properly you will  find your device in the "Devices and drives".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact answer to my problem, BUT it works now.

The steps that did not work:

- Close/open VS17
- Turn off pc,...
- Unplug Device (deactivate Developer Mode), plug in -> Error (expected) ; Unplug Device a 2nd time (activate Developer Mode), plug in -> Should have worked, but didn't
- Repair VS15 (shell)

---

I then tried three things in one session so one of those worked.

- Update VS17
- Repair VS17
- went to devices and uninstalled my WP from my devices, so that the drivers can be reinstalled.

Hope one of those works for everybody. 
I don't know what caused the Issue and if someone knows -> let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstall my phone drivers from devices,and then connect to my phone again so that drivers reinstalled,it works.